# $http post not binding with asp.net MVC model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Why is the payload from a  angularjs $http post not beeing binded to the input model?

When the action is called the model is null and the request.params and request.forms does not show any sign of a form beeing sent. But the fiddler request shows that the payload is beeing sent with JSON.

AngularJS:

```
$http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "price/add",
            data: {
                Id: $scope.id,
                StoreId: $scope.storeid,
                Name: $scope.name,
                Manufacturer: $scope.manufacturer,
                Price: $scope.price
            }
        })
```

Model:

```
public class PriceModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public int? StoreId { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public double? Price { get; set; }
    }
```

controller and action method description

```
public class PriceController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public int Add(PriceModel price)
        {
```

Fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:4989/price/add HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4989
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 70
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:4989
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:4989/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: nb,no;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

{"id":"","storeid":"","name":"asdf","manufacturer":"asdf","price":123}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if model binding is confused because the parameter is named `price` and your have a property in the `PriceModel` also called `Price`. Can you try renaming the action parameter name?

Comment: you are right! post the answer and get your reward :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if model binding is confused because the parameter is named `price` and you have a property in the `PriceModel` that's also called `Price`. Can you try renaming the action parameter name?

Comment: renaming the paramenter name worked a charm! i changed the name from price to model and it worked. Never knew!

Comment: Everything else seemed correct and that was the only thing that seems suspicious. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Just to save another person an hour, one general cause for this problem is when we use

```html
http({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        params: argument,
        headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        defered.resolve(data);
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        defered.reject(data);
    });
```

However if we change to the following works like a charm:

```html
http.post(
            url,
            argument
        ).success(function (data) {
            defered.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            defered.reject(data);
        });
```